# Is there a way to wait for a condition to be true?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm attempting to log coordinates 3 separate times when a user clicks on the turtle screen, then continue running other commands once that is completed. Clicking 3 times does nothing, and the shell keeps printing that it's waiting, while one additional click causes the whole thing to not work and I get a "not Responding" message from the turtle graphics window.

```
import turtle as t
import time
canvas=t.getcanvas()
xlist=[]
ylist=[]
listcomplete=False

def getPos(x,y):
    xlist.append(canvas.winfo_pointerx())  ##Logs the x and y coords when mouse is clicked
    ylist.append(canvas.winfo_pointery())
    print('appended the lists.')
    if len(xlist)==3:                    
        listcomplete=True

t.onscreenclick(getPos)

def main():
    while listcomplete==False:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('waiting...')     ##Prints periodically just to let me know it's still running


main()

print('list complete.')      ##Prints to alert the list has been finished
print(xlist)
(Insert rest of code to follow)
```

Comment: You get a "not responding" window if your program doesn't handle incoming Windows events. Using the turtle `mainloop()` will fix this; you should be scheduling timer events and then handling them when they come in, not sleeping in the main thread. Some variant of this is true for pretty much *every* GUI framework; it's not specific to turtle. (Those that don't require the user to run an event loop manually are still doing it under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

`listcomplete=True` within `getPos()` will not change the global variable, instead it will create a new varable of the same name within the local scope.

To change the global variable, you have to tell python to use it from the global scope:

```
def getPos(x,y):
    global listcomplete # tell python to use the variable from the global scope
    xlist.append(canvas.winfo_pointerx())  ##Logs the x and y coords when mouse is clicked
    ylist.append(canvas.winfo_pointery())
    print('appended the lists.')
    if len(xlist)==3:                    
        listcomplete=True
```

That's due to the default behavior of the assignment operator (`=`).

Other operators, such as the comparision operator (`==`) will lookup the variable from the enclosing scope(s) if it's not found within the local scope, thus you may use `while listcomplete==False:` within `main()` w/o telling pyton to use the variable from the global scope.

---

But ideally, you do not even have to use that global variable. Instead run the turtle main loop and exit the turtle window when your condition is met:

```
import turtle as t
canvas=t.getcanvas()
xlist=[]
ylist=[]

def getPos(x,y):
    xlist.append(canvas.winfo_pointerx())  ##Logs the x and y coords when mouse is clicked
    ylist.append(canvas.winfo_pointery())
    print('appended the lists.')
    if len(xlist)==3:
        t.bye() # exit turtle window

t.onscreenclick(getPos)
t.Screen().mainloop() # will wait until turtle window is closed

print('list complete.')      ##Prints to alert the list has been finished
print(xlist)
```

Comment: I did add your suggestion, but I think the issue still remains as the turtle window still crashes. I'm not sure if this is related to the issue, but the printing of "appended the lists." never occurs, which makes me think getPos() isn't even being run when I click.

Comment: @Ian I updated my answer with a tested and working code sample that does not even need a global variable.

Comment: @MikeScottyThanks, this is really neat. There's still a lot for me to learn about setting up code properly and using events and handlers. Is it possible to continue running the turtle window after the lists have been created? The x and y lists are part of the end product.

Comment: @Ian Sure, simply move the printing or whatever you want to do inside the ``if len(xlist)==3:`` block instead of exiting the turtle window.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to continue running the turtle window after the lists
>   have been created?

Things get difficult in turtle when you fight it's event-based model as you're trying to do.  Work with the model, and things get easier.  The code below presents a blank window, after you click on it in three places, it will connect your points to make a triangle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop

def getPosition(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)  # disable the handler inside the handler

    positions.append((x, y))

    if len(positions) == 3:
        screen.ontimer(listComplete)  # sometime after this function completes
    else:
        screen.onscreenclick(getPosition)  # restore the handler

def listComplete():
    for position in positions:
        turtle.goto(position)
        turtle.pendown()

    turtle.goto(positions[0])  # close our triangle

    # (Insert rest of code to follow)

positions = []

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()
screen.onscreenclick(getPosition)
mainloop()  # invoke as function to make Python 2 friendly as well
```

The key is that "rest of code to follow" will be in functions, not top level code.

Answer (score -1):

```
def handle_click(mouse_x,mouse_y):  # <== I think thats what ya need right dere, I dont think it knows you're clicking
    newpin = [[mouse_x,mouse_y], [0,0], 0,0,20, 1000000]
```

I tried putting a print statement after the click I couldn't get it to even print a test click. That may be me not trying hard enough tho ;) I just remember using something like above to handle a mouse click. (in my situation it created a pin for a pinball game) if you look up the turtle api for circle you can see the [0,0],0,0,20, 100000] means.

But ultimately that last number the 10000 whatever is "mass" so the more of it the less it moves. again my situation. turtle.onscreenclick(handle_click). Thats at least an idea :) also yes u can do a wait after an if. Throw in print statements.